# Find last id and increment values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with values as such:

```
╔════╦═════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ quarter ║ year ║ value ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║       4 ║ 2017 ║     5 ║
║  1 ║       1 ║ 2018 ║     7 ║
║  2 ║       1 ║ 2018 ║     8 ║
╚════╩═════════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

I want to find the last id and increment the quarters to 4 whilst keeping the same value. The expected output is:

```
╔════╦═════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ quarter ║ year ║ value ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║       4 ║ 2017 ║     5 ║
║  1 ║       1 ║ 2018 ║     7 ║
║  1 ║       2 ║ 2018 ║     7 ║
║  1 ║       3 ║ 2018 ║     7 ║
║  1 ║       4 ║ 2018 ║     7 ║
║  2 ║       1 ║ 2018 ║     8 ║
║  2 ║       2 ║ 2018 ║     8 ║
║  2 ║       3 ║ 2018 ║     8 ║
║  2 ║       4 ║ 2018 ║     8 ║
╚════╩═════════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

I have tried using df.last() in pandas to find the last instance of the id and increment the quarters through a loop but it does not seem to work. I am new to python and pandas so any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the last row in each group:

```
s = df.groupby('id').tail(1)
```

Then expand to four quarters:

```
out = pd.concat([s]*4).sort_values('id').assign(quarter=np.tile([1,2,3,4], len(s)))
```

Finally, merge:

```
df.merge(out, how='outer').sort_values('id')
```

```
   id  quarter  year  value
0   1        4  2017      5
1   1        1  2018      7
3   1        2  2018      7
4   1        3  2018      7
5   1        4  2018      7
2   2        1  2018      8
6   2        2  2018      8
7   2        3  2018      8
8   2        4  2018      8
```

Answer (score 2):

1st you can using `drop_duplicate` to get the last value of each id

```
df1=df.drop_duplicates('id',keep='last')

df1=df1.reindex(df1.index.repeat(4-df1.quarter+1)).assign(quarter=lambda x : x['id'].groupby(x['id']).cumcount()+x['quarter'])# then we create the target df by using reindex and assign the new value of quarter
yourdf=pd.concat([df.loc[~df.index.isin(df1.index)],df1])# concat the one we drop before we yield the result 
yourdf
Out[264]: 
   id  quarter  year  value
0   1        4  2017      5
1   1        1  2018      7
1   1        2  2018      7
1   1        3  2018      7
1   1        4  2018      7
2   2        1  2018      8
2   2        2  2018      8
2   2        3  2018      8
2   2        4  2018      8
```